# safely get variable from enviroment

Tags: r

When I execute:

```
my_env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
test <- purrr::safely(get("meta", envir = my_env))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in get("meta") : object 'meta' not found
```

The error is *correct* in the sense of that the `meta` variable is not defined in the environment but my line of thinking was that `safely` would return a `NULL` in that case.

I can get around the error by using checking using `exists` first but I was curious about why `safely` fails. Am I wrong in thinking of `safely` as the equivalent of a `try-catch`?

Comment: `get0("meta", envir = my_env, ifnotfound = NA)`

Comment: @Jraku56: Even using `try` will not prevent error messages from being reported. To accomplish that you would need to falsify reporting with `options`. See the example in `?try`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the actions of the `safely` function. It was actually succeeding. If you had examined the value of `test`, you should have seen:

```
> test
[1] "Error in get(\"meta\", env = my_env) : object 'meta' not found\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in get("meta", env = my_env): object 'meta' not found
```

To suppress error messages from being visible at the console you can either turn off reporting with `options(show.error.messages = FALSE)` or you can redirect the destination of `stderr()`.